# Serve static content without stopping halting following middleware - Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to add a database to the game of snake I made in javascript, I have it hosted on heroku and am using express to serve the static content. The problem I am encountering is although I can POST data to my database on mlab, I can't GET the results when the static content is served before the GET request. However, if I put it after the GET request I don't get anything except the GET response on my page. I need the static content to be loaded, and then a GET request to return previous scores.

example:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
db.collection('scores')
  .find({}, {sort: {_id: -1}})
  .toArray((error, accounts) => {
    if (error) return next(error)
    res.send(accounts)
 })
})
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

will return the right data from the database, but will not serve static content, and reversing the order will load the static content, but consequent GET requests will result in just the html from the page being returned.

the HTML looks like this

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Snake</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"> </canvas>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

I removed the ../server.js because I realized it was not needed, I serve the static content with the following line

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'static')))
```

Comment: You need to have separate routes for things that you want static pages served for and things you want database requests via Ajax.  These two should not overlap.  Then you will not have conflicts between static pages and custom routes.  You only get to send one response for each incoming request so it's not clear why you want both a static page and a database request to both be sent.  The client is either requesting an HTML page or some data, not both.

Comment: I created a separate route and that fixed it thank you so much, I wasn't sure what the problem was. The explanation makes a lot of sense, I only started working with node and express recently so I was unaware it would create a conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it solved your problem:

You need to have separate routes for things that you want static pages served for and things you want database requests via Ajax. These two URLs should not overlap.

Then you will not have conflicts between static pages and custom routes. You only get to send one response for each incoming request so it's not clear why you want both a static page and a database request to both be sent. The client is either requesting an HTML page or some data, not both.

Comment: Just a quick question, for separate routes I would add an extension onto my app url in the Ajax request as well as the get and post method in the node file correct? For example in my node I would define serve static using one url ie. /static and then get and post would be something like /requests? Then my Ajax would be XMLHttpRequest.open("GET", "/requests", true)? I am trying to do that and if I visit /requests I get the response but my static content is not served and additionally results in a content security policy error.

Comment: @rsingh - You'd have to show the actual client side HTML and/or Ajax for me to understand what you're doing.  If you have static HTML files and within those static HTML files you have other static resources (like script files or CSS files or images) and you want those to work properly with your `express.static()`, then you have to make the URLs for those are also lined up with what the path is for the `express.static()`.  Without seeing exactly what you're doing, it's kind of hard to know where you went wrong.

Comment: all the static files are kept in a folder called static, the server.js file is in the parent directory of the static folder.
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="../server.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
they are linked to the html using the lines above, and the Ajax requests look like 
xhr.open("GET","https://jssnake.herokuapp.com/endgame",true);
followed by the send and the xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {handle async response}
in the server.js file I have app.get('/endgame', retrieve data from mongodb)

Comment: @rsingh - I need to see ACTUAL HTML formatted properly and pasted into your question.  We can't read multiline code or HTML in comments.  Personally, I would never use `../server.js` in an HTML file - not sure what you're trying to accomplish with that.  What it does would depend upon the URL of the containing HTML file.  My guess is that you have a problem with relative URLs in your HTML file, but there's not enough info here for me to be more specific than that.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the HTML, thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Your line of code `app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'static')))` expects all static resources to have a path that starts with `/static`, but none of the resources in your HTML file have that at the start of their path.  Perhaps you just want: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'static')))` and then make sure your other routes are defined before this.

Comment: I fixed the path, and removed the inline javascript on the body tag and it is working now. Thank you so much for all your help.